# Public key collision/address reuse and HD wallet path search space

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets

If you load the same key and the correct path into different wallets, and it properly generates a new address for every transaction, would the two wallets generate the same address in a sequential fashion? Or could it conceivably sit there for years, searching through billions of addresses?